# Remove spacing between buttons

Tags: html, css, button, spacing

so I would like to remove the spacing between these buttons. But removing the margin doesn't do it.

When I go into Inspect, it also says that there is nothing there, so I don't get why it does this.

**HTML:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<input class="button" type="button" value="1">
<input class="button" type="button" value="2">
<input class="button" type="button" value="3">
<input class="button" type="button" value="4">
```

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1:**

Add `display: flex;` to parent div.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="1">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="2">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="3">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="4">
</div>
```

**Solution 2:** Don't break line on HTML.

```html
<input class="button" type="button" value="1"><input class="button" type="button" value="2"><input class="button" type="button" value="3"><input class="button" type="button" value="4">
```

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way is to put them all on one line:

```
<input class="button" type="button" value="1"><input class="button" type="button" value="2"><input class="button" type="button" value="3"><input class="button" type="button" value="4">
```

Other options include using floats or flexbox.

Answer (score -2):

Browsers always add spaces between some elements, like buttons. To remove these, you need to set `font-size` to zero, in their parent container. Then, to restore text size inside buttons, set `font-size` in them. Here's a snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

#parent {
  font-size: 0;
}

.button {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="1">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="2">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="3">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="4">
</div>
```